# Verificar se texto pertence ao elemento e não ao filho

Tags: javascript, html

Por exemplo, na estrutura abaixo eu tenho uma `div` que possui um texto e outra `div` que também possui um texto. Como eu posso capturar ou verificar se um texto é filho direto de uma tag, e não filho de uma outra tag filha:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.div1').textContent)
```

```css
.div1{
  background: #ccc;  
  padding: 10px
}
.div2{
  background: #999;  
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Texto filho direto da div1
  <div class="div2">
    Texto filho direto da div2 e filho indireto da div1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de visualmente não ser visível esse texto e o elemento filho são *nós* (`nodes`) diferentes. E podes verificar isso com [`.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

Neste caso os tipos 1 e 3 é o que procuras distinguir:

> **Node.ELEMENT_NODE**  `1` Um elemento como `<p>` ou `<div>`.
>   **Node.TEXT_NODE**     `3` O texto de um elemento ou atributo.

Assim, para capturar somente o texto e não o conteúdo da descendencia:

```js
var pai = document.querySelector('.div1');
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < pai.childNodes.length; ++i) {
  var el = pai.childNodes[i];
  if (el.nodeType === 3) text += el.textContent;
}

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Texto filho direto da div1
  <div class="div2">
    Texto filho direto da div2 e filho indireto da div1
  </div>
</div>
```